# Android Back Navigation to parent activity

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

How can I realize that back navigation from an activity A is calling the activity B defined as parent activity in the android manifest although activity B has never be shown before.

Using in A.java the code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

did not work for me (this closes activity A but does not show activity B).

Comment: what does navigateUpFromSameTask(this) method does ?Post rhe NavUtils class

Comment: Are you planning this for notification flow? Because this behavior can be achieved by PendingIntent and TaskStackBuilder

Comment: from the documentation: _To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the NavUtils class's static method, navigateUpFromSameTask(). When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward._